# WOPI put document request not receiving at end point *POST files/fileid/contents*

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, office365, ms-wopi

I have implemented the WOPI end points, all end points are working fine but when I am editing the document online, It is not giving save back request as put document endpoint.

And most importantly, When it'll be saved because there is nothing defined in the document that when it'll call you back for the update document call as if we editing document, its not possible to having it saved automatically, if so,than we'll get so many requests of put document after every line of changes we made in the document.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, the save requests are called after every few changes made to the document and always when you close the document.

To avoid unnecessary traffic, you should implement [[MS-FSSHTTP]](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd956775(v=office.12).aspx) (File Synchronization over HTTP) protocol in your WOPI host to support so-called "Cobalt" requests. This ensures only diffs will be sent between WOPI client and WOPI host. Microsoft's implementation can be found in the `Microsoft.CobaltCore.dll` assembly.

Here's a video describing how [FSSHTTP](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Open-Specifications-Plugfests/Redmond-Interoperability-Protocols-Plugfest-2015/FSSHTTP-File-Synchronization-over-HTTP) works.